# Get a one value of a more dimensional array and put it in one dimensional array

Tags: c#

I have an array with records on but its a more dimensional array. Now I only want two values in every dimension. I want to put them in two seperated arrays. So my question is how can I put a value of more dimensional array in one dimensional array. Code below data0 is my one dimensional array where i want to put the first value of every part of my  more dimensional array.

I want to put myrecords[0] (multi-array)  in data0[0] (one-array).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUktY.png)

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\elyag\\Dropbox\\A Thesis\\Programma C#\\Programma_voor_User_interface_wijziging\\C#\\bin\\breng hier data in\\1000 1000\\DebugDT9857E_channel0_Channel1metfoam.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
double[] data0 = new double[numberOfBuffers*samplesperbuffer];
// string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path");

string[][] myRecords = new string[numberOfBuffers * samplesperbuffer][];
int k = 0;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (myRecords[k] == null) myRecords[k] = new string[values.Length + 1];
        myRecords[k][i] = values[i];
        data0[i] = Convert.ToDouble(myRecords[i][0]);
    }
    k++;
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Your last **for loop** seems incorrect, shouldn't it be `for (int i = 0; i < values.Length-1; i++)` instead?

Comment: my error message is: the object reference is not set on an instance of an object.

Comment: `myRecords[k]` is initially always `null`. Why don't you initialize before the inner loop? `var values = ...; myRecords[k] = new string[values.Length]; for (...) { ... }`

Comment: the myrecords array is quite big (1000000). I want to this 1000000 times and put  a value in a specific place of myrecords  values in data0[0]..

Comment: I've added a picture of myrecords. I only want the value in place [0] of myrecords and put them in a one dim array data0

Comment: In the string
data0[i] = Convert.ToDouble(myRecords[i][0]);
Shouldn't you be using [k][0] in the last index?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to put the values into a list. Unlike arrays, lists grow automatically as you add items

If data must contain **all the values**:

```
var data = new List<double>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(new char[]{' '},
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(value));
    }
}
double[] dataArray = data.ToArray();
```

If data must contain only the **first value** of each line

```
var data = new List<double>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(new char[]{' '},
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (values.Length > 0) { // Just in case the last line is empty.
        data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[0]));
    }
}
double[] dataArray = data.ToArray();
```

---

Your code is quite confusing, because you are creating an array whose length is `numberOfBuffers * samplesperbuffer` and which contains another array for each element. I.e., in total, it will contain `numberOfBuffers * samplesperbuffer * lengthOfSingleLines` elements. It this what you want? Or should the final one-dimensional array contain only `numberOfBuffers * samplesperbuffer` elements where samplesperbuffer is the number of values per text line?

If this is the case, you can change the example to produce the final array directly

```
var data = new double[numberOfBuffers * samplesperbuffer];
int k = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(new char[]{' '},
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        data[k++] = Convert.ToDouble(value));
    }
}
```

---

See also: [Multi-dimensional and Jagged Arrays](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/multidimensional-arrays-csharp)

Comment: But I have two colums as data. How can I split them in the dataaray? I've splitted them with \t. I only want the first column in the dataArray.

Comment: your first code is correct, but I have 2 columns with data in that text file. If i run your code it gives in the 2 columns on the array mixed. I only want to show my first colulmn in the array. I've splitted it wit \t.

Comment: 1) Is `numberOfBuffers` equal to the number of lines and `samplesperbuffer` equal 2? and 2) Do you also need the two dimensional array? 3) If you only want to store the first value of each line why not `double[] data0 = new double[numberOfBuffers];`

Comment: no i dont need the two dimensional aray anymore , i will put it in the list.

Comment: Do have to add a [0] component in the code to let them know that I only want the first column in the array?

Comment: If you have two entries per line, then the `values` array will have the two elements `values[0]` and `values[1]`. Pick the first one with `values[0]`.

Comment: High thanks for, the answer. It worked. But the  ToArray() takes only the half of my lines in the list. How do I take the whole list in my aray? (example I have 1000 lines in column 0, but it only takes 500 of the lines). Can I set the array size?

Comment: `ToArray()` always takes all the lines. There must be missing lines in the list already.